# Output generated is different with output in NLTK tutorial

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, nltk

Today I start to learn Python because I need to use NLTK in my assignment. In order to learn it, I follow the tutorial in this site http://www.nltk.org/book/ch01.html. However, when I run the programme in Python interpreter, the output produced is not same with what has been shown in the website and I have no idea on what thing that this output wants to tell me.

(Below is the picture of the output:)

Input: >>> from nltk.book import *

[Output (After I hit 'Enter'):](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T6PdV.png)

So now my questions are what is the error about and if there is a way to solve it, then what should I need to do?

Thanks for looking into my problem.

Comment: welcome to Stackoverflow. Do you mind telling us how you installed python and NLTK?

Comment: Please copy & paste the complete stack trace and error message instead of posting images.  It's much more helpful if other people run into this problem and can search for the error message.

Comment: @alvas Sorry dude, since the problem is solved, I think I am not going to post this extra information.

Comment: @John Wiseman Thanks for advice and I will keep it in my mind :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a [known bug with nltk and Python 3](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/issues/1106).  It seems to have been fixed within the past two weeks, but I expect you'll have to wait until there's a release that contains the fix.  You could try installing from source.

Comment: Thanks for the information! After I read your comment, I uninstalled Python 3.5 followed by installed 3.4 and now it works like a charm :)

Comment: @Elisa, That's not exactly the solution in the long run but i guess whatever works =)